# Microstrategy - Create simple graph

Tags: csv, visualization, metrics, microstrategy

I've a  very simple table (CSV) that I've imported into mycrostrategy to visualize my data.

The data represents the points of certain teams (e.g. football) for each played round (*px*).

csv:

```
#teams, p1, p2, p3, p4
Team1,  3,  6,  6,  7
Team2,  0,  0,  3,  4
Team3,  3,  6,  9,  12
Team4,  1,  4,  7,  8
```

The expected graph ( I did this one in Excel) is attached.

[image]

This seems very simple to me to do, but so far, I could not figure out how  to organize the data (attributes/metrics, etc) to create this visualization.

Any idea? Is there any metric that I've to create (like max number Points)..

**EDIT:**
The best I could do was a 'discrete' representation (see attach) of the data with Dots, I'd like to have a line/continuous.

*Solution with dots instead of a line connecting the dots*
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your data using the [Crosstab option](https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Web/TN227008-How-to-switch-between-Crosstab-or-Tabular-when-import/ta-p/227008).

You should create two attributes:

- Team (team1, team2, team3, team4)
- Player Rounds (p1, p2, p3, p4)

And a Points metric.

With these three elements you should be able to create your graph easily.

Comment: Hum, many thanks. I tried crosstab before but did not create the attributes. Will try and evaluate your proposal later. Thanks

Comment: I tried this solution (crosstab creation on the parse option) and then create the attributes. Not sure what would be the syntax for the attribute creation. This task seems to be very simple, but so far no success.

Comment: I was able to create the above graph from the csv data you supplied. When importing the data, use the Parse.. Crosstab option. Highlight the "Metrics values" and select "No metric headers". This should give you columns for "teams", "column 2" (p1, p2 etc) and "metrics". From this dataset create a dashboard with a line chart visualisation, Vertical = Metrics, Horizontal="column2", Colour By="teams".